# Using NSScanner to separate string into NSArray by comma

Tags: objective-c, csv, nsstring, nsarray, nsscanner

Does anyone know how i can use NSScanner to separate  a string by comma into an array EXCEPT when a comma is embedded within quotes?

Before i had been using:

```
  NSArray *arrData = [strData componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

However i have quotes inside the string that have commas inside them, i want these not to be separated. I have never worked with NSScanner before and i am struggling to come to terms with the documentation. Has anyone done a similar thing before?

Comment: Why don't you try modifying the componentsSeparatedByString value from @"," to @"\",\"" .

Comment: Your need is to use NSScanner or for this case, you think it can't be done in normal ways.?

Comment: I believe the only ways are NSScanner or NSRegularExpressions however i have never worked with either before so i am a bit lost as to what to do.

Comment: I respect your belief. Try escaping the double quote as suggested by me. Let me know.

Comment: I did and it didn't work but thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you have a CSV file. If so, you might want to consider a proper [CSV parser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use an NSScanner you could do something like this.

```
        NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"\"Foo, Inc\",0.00,1.00,\"+1.5%\",\"+0.2%\",\"Foo"];
        NSCharacterSet *characters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\","];
        [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
        NSMutableArray *words = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableString *word = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        BOOL inQuotes = NO;
        while(scanner.isAtEnd == NO)
        {
            NSString *subString;
            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:characters intoString:&subString];
            NSUInteger currentLocation = [scanner scanLocation];
            if(currentLocation >= scanner.string.length)
            {
                if(subString.length > 0)
                    [words addObject:subString];
                break;
            }
            if([scanner.string characterAtIndex:currentLocation] == '"')
            {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                if(subString == nil)
                {
                    [scanner setScanLocation:currentLocation + 1];
                    continue;
                }
                [word appendFormat:@"%@",subString];
                if(word.length > 0)
                   [words addObject:word.copy];
                [word deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, word.length)];
            }
            if([scanner.string characterAtIndex:currentLocation] == ',')
            {
                if(subString == nil)
                {
                    [scanner setScanLocation:currentLocation + 1];
                    continue;
                }
                if(inQuotes == NO)
                    [words addObject:subString];
                else
                    [word appendFormat:@"%@,",subString];
            }
            [scanner setScanLocation:currentLocation + 1];
        }
```

**EDIT:**
This gives the following output:

> Foo, Inc
>
> 0.00
>
> 1.00
>
> +1.5%
>
> +0.2%
>
> Foo

Hope this is what you want

As you can see it gets complicated and very error prone, I would recommend using Regex for this.

Comment: that keeps crashing for me when i insert my own string. Maybe regex would be better. How would i split it into an array using regex though?

Comment: Still no luck. Heres a copy of my string if it helps: "Foo, Inc",0.00,1.00,"+1.5%","+0.2%","Foo"

Comment: I clearly can't write proper code without debugging it. My updated code should work

Comment: This is how is what the array looks like after i looped through each index:Item 0: Foo
Item 1:  Inc"
Item 2: 0.00
Item 3: 1.00
Item 4: "+1.5%","+0.2%","Foo Is there a way of doing it with regex?

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? It didn't split that part of the string. I know very basic regex sorry. Someone can help you better.

Comment: I wanted the data to be like this item 1: "Foo, Inc" item 2: 0.00 item 3: "+1.5%" item 4:"+0.2%". However thank you for all your time @lead_the_zeppelin

Comment: I think you missed 1.00 and Foo from your output. Check my code now. It should work! Whew

Comment: Voted up. But with this note - this code skips empty elements ("").
Here is my working (changed part) of code:

Comment: if([scanner.string characterAtIndex:currentLocation] == '"')
            {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                if((subString == nil)&&(!([scanner.string characterAtIndex:currentLocation+1] == '"')))
                {
                    [scanner setScanLocation:currentLocation + 1];
                    continue;
                }
                else if (subString == nil){subString = @" ";}
                [word appendFormat:@"%@",subString];
                ...etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is the same general procedure as [lead_the_zeppelin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23145913/603977), but I think it's considerably more straightforward. We use an `NSMutableString`, `accum`, to build up each intra-comment piece, which may consist of any number of quoted segments.

Each iteration, we scan up to a comma, a quote, or the end of the string, whichever comes first. If we find a comma, whatever's been accumulated so far should be saved. For a quote, we pick up everything up to the closing quote mark -- this is the key that avoids interpreting commas inside quotations as split points. Note that this *won't work* if quotes are not always balanced. If it's neither of those, we've reached the end of the string, so we save the accumulated string and quit.

```
// Demo data
NSArray * commaStrings = @[@"This, here, \"has\" no quoted, commas.",
                           @"This \"has, no\" unquoted \"commas,\"",
                           @"This, has,no,quotes",
                           @"This has no commas",
                           @"This has, \"a quoted\" \"phrase, followed\", by a, quoted phrase",
                           @"\"This\", one, \"went,\", to, \"mar,ket\"",
                           @"This has neither commas nor quotes",
                           @"This ends with a comma,"];

NSCharacterSet * commaQuoteSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",\""];

for( NSString * commaString in commaStrings ){

    NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:commaString];
    // Scanner ignores whitespace by default; turn that off.
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    NSMutableArray * splitStrings = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSMutableString * accum = [NSMutableString new];

    while( YES ){

        // Set to an empty string for the case where the scanner is
        // at the end of the string and won't scan anything;
        // appendString: will die if its argument is nil.
        NSString * currScan = @"";
        // Scan up to a comma or a quote; this will go all the way to
        // the end of the string if neither of those exists.
        [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:commaQuoteSet
                                intoString:&currScan];
        // Add the just-scanned material to whatever we've already got.
        [accum appendString:currScan];

        if( [scanner scanString:@"," intoString:NULL] ){
            // If it's a comma, save the accumulated string,
            [splitStrings addObject:accum];
            // clear it out,
            accum = [NSMutableString new];
            // and keep scanning.
            continue;
        }
        else if( [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL] ) {
            // If a quote, append the quoted segment to the accumulation,
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"\""
                         intoString:&currScan];
            [accum appendFormat:@"\"%@\"", currScan];
            // and continue, appending until the next comma.
            [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL];
            continue;
        }
        else {
            //Otherwise, there's nothing else to split; 
            // just save the remainder of the string
            [splitStrings addObject:accum];
            break;
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%@", splitStrings);
}
```

Also, [as Chuck suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145763/using-nsscanner-to-separate-string-into-nsarray-by-comma#comment35393124_23145763), you might want to just get a CSV parser.